# Edit all visual studio pages at same time

Tags: c#

I have 30 visual studio 2010 express forms, can I add a control to one form and replicate it to the other 29 forms or do I have to edit them all separately?

Answer (score 0):

If you want separate functionality for all the forms then you need to edit in each form.

Comment: If I wanted to add a home button to each page so the code would be the same on all home buttons etc.

Comment: Then better you go with user control........ and separate functionality you can write in individual forms.....

Comment: so basically if I wanted to add a home button to allready created forms be it 1 or 10 or 30 or 1000 I would have to manually add a home button to each form?

Comment: If its an Windows application with MDI then you can add a link in MDI parent for "HOME". Other wise create BASE form with HOME button and inherit all the forms with BASE form.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "Visual Studio Express Forms", so I will assume you meant "Windows Forms" Forms from the .NET Framework.

If you created 30 of them by hand, then you will need to add your home button to all 30 of them. If the home button is always at the same position and always does the same thing, then it might be easier to derive your own class from [System.windows.Forms.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) and add the button to your base class. Then you only need to replace all your created forms' base classes, which are  plain "Form"s, by your own, Form-Derived class that already includes the home button.