# Is there a way to edit multiple files at the same time in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have 15 different .html files, and I want to add a new button / link to them, and I was wondering is there a way to edit all of them at the same time / add the button / link to all of them at once, or do I need to do it all manually for each file?

The button I will be adding has the same function on all pages.
I have read this :
[Edit all visual studio pages at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039196/edit-all-visual-studio-pages-at-same-time) question, but it didn't really help, plus I think it might as well be outdated, since it's from 2013.

I am using Visual Studio Code editor.

Comment: Can you solve it with a search and replace?

Comment: use a template engine that allows inheritance and block replacement, the Django template engine has this feature and with a bit of work you can extract it and use separate